# Selenium/Python - Element click intercepted error with multiple elements

Tags: python, selenium, error-handling

In trying to scrape a website I'm encountering the following error: **"Message: element click intercepted: Element img src="/Matrix/Images/Icons/16/Info.png border="0"> is not clickable at point (970, 8)."**

The issue seems to be coming from my list of links (lst_of_links).

Most solutions I found required adding `until(EC.element_to_be_clickable()`, however, it's not apparent to me how to do this with a list of elements as opposed to a single element.

Thoughts welcome.

```
        #List of links to all scrape pages
        lst_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[@src='/Matrix/Images/Icons/16/Info.png']")

        #For Loop to cycle through all items
        for link in lst_of_links:
           
            #Click on all item information Icons 
            link.click()
```

Comment: Can you provide the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try scrolling each element into view and only after that click on it, like this:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)

lst_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[@src='/Matrix/Images/Icons/16/Info.png']")
for link in lst_of_links:
    actions.move_to_element(link).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    link.click()
```